# Isomorphic React App markup reuse error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I'm building a very simple isomorphic React/Redux app and in one of my containers I want to load a user's details and a list of their albums.

Everything works okay both server and client side but I get the error:

```
Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
 (client) iv data-reactid="2">Loading...</div></di
 (server) iv data-reactid="2"><a href="/users" dat
```

I understand that this is because on load the server and client may be different because the client takes longer to fetch the data. However how to I get around this issue?

If I remove the `{!user}` return, then the page doesn't render and I get an error message saying that `{user.firstName}` does not exist.

Here's my component code:

```
// IMPORT DEPENDENCIES
// ==============================================

import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getAlbumsByUserId} from '../../redux/album/albumActions';
import {getUser} from '../../redux/user/userActions';

// USER CONTAINER
// ==============================================

export class User extends Component {

static propTypes = {
    getAlbumsByUserId: PropTypes.func,
    getUser: PropTypes.func,
    params: PropTypes.object,
    user: PropTypes.object
};

static needs = [
    getAlbumsByUserId,
    getUser
];

componentWillMount () {
    this.props.getAlbumsByUserId();
    this.props.getUser();
}

render () {
    const {albums, user} = this.props;

    if (!user) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Link to='/users'>Back to users</Link>
            <h1>User: {user.firstName} {user.lastName}</h1>

            {albums &&
                albums.map((album) =>
                    <div key={album.id}>
                        <h2>
                            <Link to={`/albums/${album.id}`}>
                                {album.title}
                            </Link>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
}
}





// MAPPINGS
// ==============================================

const mapStateToProps = ({albums, users}) => {
    return {
        albums: albums.list.items,
        user: users.activeItem.item
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
    return {
        getAlbumsByUserId: () => { dispatch   (getAlbumsByUserId(props.params)); },
        getUser: () => { dispatch(getUser(props.params)); }
    };
};





// EXPORT
// ==============================================

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(User);
```

the `static needs` tells the server which actions it requires on page load.

Comment: in client side it displays <div>Loading...</div>, in server side it displays <a href="/users"... Check that you are sending the same data on client and server side (here it seems **the user property is null on client side**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears I needed to use `ComponentDidMount` rather than `ComponentWillMount`

Answer (score -1):

Usually, when dealing with isomorphic way we pass the `inital data` from server along with index file rather then loading the data using ajax. 
e.g. in our main HTML file we'll have something like

```
<script>
  var APP_PROPS = JSON.stringify(props);
</script>
```

and use this data for initial rendering.

Comment: I do have this, however the initial state becomes obsolete once I start changing routes.

Comment: Serializing initial data with JSON.stringify will make your application vulnerable to XSS attacks. You should use serialize-javascript (or something like that) instead.

Comment: Agreed, this for demo and easy understanding purpose. We've wrapper around JSON.stringify to remove tags (scripts and all) and some special characters